# adjusting for browser font width variations in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script that takes the items in the navigation bar, and stretches each row except the last to the width of the menu's container. The process is basically:

-Find the menu container width
-Iterate through each item, adding the `.outerWidth(true)` to a variable containing the current row width
-When the current row width becomes greater than or equal to the container width run a few tests
--subtract `.outerWidth(true)` from current row width and add `.innerWidth().`
--if row width is still greater than container width, move to the next row array, and add the current item as the first item in the row,
--if the row width is equal to or less than the container width, add the item as the last item of the current row, and move to the next row array.

Once the rows have been created, calculated the necessary padding to add to each element by finding the difference between the container width and the row width and following the following formula:

```
this.addedPadding = Math.floor( this.difference / ( this.items.length * 2) );
```

then calculate the leftover space by:

```
this.leftovers = this.difference - (this.addedPadding * 2 * this.items.length);
```

Then proceed to iterate through all items, adding the added padding. Then take `leftovers`, iterate it downwards by 2's, adding 1px of padding to each side of the first element, then second, third, and so on until `leftovers` is equal to 1 or 0. If it equals one, add one px of padding to the `padding-right` of the last item in the row.

Iterate through each row, and repeat the process.

Now, the problem is, different browsers render font slightly differently, so the numbers don't always add up perfectly. My current solution is to change the container width by the necessary adjustment by the browser so that the rows render correctly. This doesn't even have consistent results. For instance, on the site I'm working on, in Chrome, the homepage renders incorrectly at first, but (at least on my computer) if you refresh, it renders correctly.

What would be the correct way to address this without having to change the containerWidth based on browser and content? Is there a way?

For an example of the issue, visit http://development.rjhallsted.com/login_system/browsing/projects/insidemt/

Comment: There is a `.width()` method in jQuery.

Comment: A suggestion, why not use responsive templates?

Comment: I used `.innerWidth()` and `.outerWidth()` so I could differentiate between widths with margin and widths without.

Comment: The theme template itself that I am using is responsive. I wanted the nav to be the width of the screen, which was not include with the theme.

Comment: edit - I wanted the nav to be the width of the containing element